# PHP how to call function from another class?

Tags: php

I have a class `Database` in `database.php` with 145 functions(17,000 lines) and now i've read this is bad practice, so i want sort out the functions correctly into specific classes rather than a "God" Class.

What i want to know is how do i call a function from another class?  Below is an example;  How do i call function two from within function one?

database.php

```
require("connect.php");

class Database {
private $connect;

function one() {
//call function two
}

}
```

forms.php

```
require("connect.php");

class Forms {
private $connect;

function two() {
//returns forms
}

}
```

How do i do this?

Comment: How do you usually call functions of a class? You create an object and then? :)

Comment: Do i include 'forms.php'; at the top of database.php?

Comment: You'd have a problem if you did that. Both files require connect.php User require_once instead

Comment: So should i remove require connect.php from forms class?  In forms class i also connect to the database.

Comment: Change require to require_once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you gave you would do:

```
function one() {
    $forms = new Forms;
    $forms->two();
}
```

Another option would be

```
function one() {
      Forms::two();
   }
```

And in Forms you would change the method to:

```
static function two() {

   }
```